# System.invalidoperationexception xmlmodels are not editable

Tags: tfs, entity-framework-5, edmx

I have a problem I can not solve.
I have a edmx in my project and when I try to update I get this error:

An exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException` occurred while attempting to update the database. `Exception Message: The XmlModels involved in this transaction are not editable`.

Also I have in my TFS output:
`TF10121: The path '\\\ C: \ Workspace \ C # \ wk_kapseo \ V5.6EDMX \ Kapseo_BDD \ LynxModel.edmx.diagram'` was not found or is not supported. Type or select another path.

But I do not understand why?
I tried to delete and regenerate the edmx but it is similar.
I do not see what to try.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exception **'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred while attempting to update the database. Exception Message: The XmlModels involved in this transaction are not editable.** in the past.

In my case the problem occurred because the Visual Studio entity framework designer *update model from database* feature did not like when the file path to my model contained the characters 'C#'.

Comment: This bug is still in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.6.5.  Hard to believe Microsoft hasn't fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` problem in the directory path can also prevent a new edmx creation.
I had the exception

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

and the output error

> TF10121: The path \\C:\Sources\C#\Model1.edmx.diagram is not
>   found or not supported. Type or select a different path.